# Problem migrating Drupal 6 location fields to Drupal 7

Tags: location, migrations

I am currently writing a migration from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. I am using the Migrate module (2.7), Drupal-to-Drupal migration module (2.1) and migrate extras (2.5). I have been successful in migrating images, files, boolean, text, and list fields but have hit a brick wall with location fields.

I have tried mapping the source location cck field directly to the Drupal 7 location cck field. This migration runs with no errors but doesn't actually migrate any data.

```
 $this->addFieldMapping('field_location','field_event_location');
```

I have also tried mapping the sub-fields of the location field using the below link as reference:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2018113

```
//Mapping location field
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location','field_event_location');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:name', 'name');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:street', 'street');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:additional', 'additional');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:city', 'city');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:province', 'province');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:postal_code', 'postal_code');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:country', 'country');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:latitude', 'latitude');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:longitude', 'longitude');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:source', 'source');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_location:is_primary', 'is_primary');

  protected function query() {
    $query = parent::query();

    // Join location table
    $query->join('location_instance', 'i', 'i.nid = n.nid AND i.vid = n.vid');
    $query->join('location', 'l', 'l.lid = i.lid');
    $query->fields('l', array('name', 'street', 'additional', 'city', 'province', 'postal_code', 'country', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'source', 'is_primary'));

    return $query;
  }
```

This throws 'SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264' errors

Example error:

```
    SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 
'is_primary' at row 1: INSERT INTO {location} (name, street, additional, city, province, 
postal_code, country, latitude, longitude, source, is_primary) VALUES 
(:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, 
:db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, 
:db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, 
:db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] 
=> Talk at somewhere [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 Some Road [:db_insert_placeholder_2] 
=> [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => Somewhere [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => XXX XXX [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => uk 
[:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 53.321524 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => -1.509733 
[:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 448 ) 
(C:\wamp\www\\includes\common.inc:7291)
```

Which seems to be adding a value of 448 to the is_primary field. This value increments through the errors thrown.

I have tried setting the is_primary default value to 0 using:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:is_primary', 'is_primary')->defaultValue('0');
```

AND

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:is_primary', 'is_primary')->defaultValue(0);
```

The result of this is the same errors.

I have also tried setting the value using a callback:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:is_primary', 'is_primary')
->callbacks(array($this, 'fixIsPrimary'));

protected function fixIsPrimary($is_primary_value) {
      if(True){
        $is_primary_value = 0;
      }
      return $is_primary_value;
  }
```

With the same results. I have also tried not mapping the field using:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:is_primary', 'is_primary')->issueGroup(t('DNM'));
```

With the same results. I have also tried not mapping the field at all:

```
//$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:is_primary', 'is_primary');
```

With little effect.

If anyone with more experience with Drupal migrations could offer an insight into location fields, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom Sage